# Timer inside WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, .net-4.0, timer

I have a WCF service hosted inside IIS.  Every now and then I need to clean up internal structures and would like to have a timer that kicks off every hour.

I run this statement to setup a timer:

```
using System.Threading;
...
...
_timerMisc = new Timer(timerMisc_OnTimer, new object(), Timeout.Infinite, 60 * 60 * 1000);

private void timerMisc_OnTimer(object state)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

The timer never kicks off.  What am I missing?  Is this even a possibility on a IIS-hosted WCF service?

Comment: Just set WAS to recycle the worker process instead of coding this.

Answer (score 4):

Running Timer or any scheduling mechanism within IIS-hosted environment is not recommended because apps will get recycled from time to time.

Setting Timeout.Infinite will prevent your timer from starting.  If you want to start it immediately, set it to 0 instead.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that using long-running timers in an IIS-hosted WCF service is not reliable, it can be useful to run short-lived timer operations from within an IIS-hosted WCF service as a temporary solution.

### My solution after experiencing a similar issue

Start the timer during a service operation so it has the correct context, rather than starting the timer from the constructor. SynchronizationContext.Current is available during service operations, but not during construction.  Make sure you set a global flag to indicate whether the timer has been started to ensure that it does not start multiple times.

### Caveats

That solution works only if the following conditions are true:

- The service's InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single.  I happen to use ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, but that setting likely would not affect the timer.
- The service operation during which you start the timer will be called early in the service's lifecycle and you don't need the timer to run before any service operations are called, hence a recommendation to move timed operations to a separate application that runs constantly, and then execute service operations from there.

If those caveats don't contradict your solution, here's an example:

```
Public Function ServiceOperationA(Data As Object) As Object Implements IService.ServiceOperationA
    ActivateTimers_SyncContextRequired()

    'Other operation actions...'
End Function

Private TimersActivated_SyncContextPresent As Boolean = False
Private ReadOnly ActivatingTimers_SyncContextPresent As New Object
Friend Sub ActivateTimers_SyncContextRequired()
    Dim ExitSub As Boolean = False
    SyncLock ActivatingTimers_SyncContextPresent
        If TimersActivated_SyncContextPresent Then ExitSub = True
        TimersActivated_SyncContextPresent = True
    End SyncLock
    If ExitSub Then Exit Sub

    TimersActivated_SyncContextRequired = True
    timerCheckData = New System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds)
    timerCheckData.AutoReset = True
    AddHandler timerCheckData.Elapsed, AddressOf timerCheckData_Elapsed
    timerCheckData.Start()
End Sub

Friend Sub timerCheckData_Elapsed()
    'Timed operations...'
End Sub
```

I intend to move timed functionality to a Windows Service or maybe ASP.Net + Hangfire: www.hangfire.io, and then execute timed service operations from there; you could also host your WCF service in a Windows Service rather than IIS, or use SignalR if that meets your needs best.